# Get record having highest date inside nested group in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having a record set like below :

[image]

I need to write a query where foreach datatype of every parent I show the data type with highest date i.e

[image]

So far I am able to create two groups one on parent id & other on data type but i am unable to understand how to get record with max date.
Below is my query :

```
db.getCollection('Maintenance').aggregate( [{ $group : 
{ _id :{ parentName: "$ParentID" , maintainancename : "$DataType" }}},
{ $group : { 
      _id :  "$_id.parentName",
      maintainancename: { 
          $push: { 
              term:"$_id.DataType"
              }
      }
   }
 }] )
```

Comment: Please post sample docs in text format not in pictures..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to `$group` twice, try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** group on two fields `ParentID` & `Datatype`,
   * which will leave docs with unique `ParentID + Datatype` 
   * & use `$max` to get max value on `Date` field in unique set of docs */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        parentName: "$ParentID",
        maintainancename: "$Datatype"
      },
      "Date": { $max: "$Date" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/flaCxub5BbJ)

**Note :** After group stage you can use `$project` or `$addFields`stages to transform fields the way you want.

Comment: how to use project in given query ?

Comment: @pankaj : what output are you looking at ? Check if this what you wanted :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/FVQsBUv34t-)